# WPF: Binding to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Well, I have couple of problem with DataGrid in WPF.

1. I have a Progress Bar in DataGrid which I want to show value from Database [Well complete DataGrid is bound to Datatable which I fetch from Database].
2. I have a Status as Enum in my code, and it's numeric value is store in database, though it is databind properly, I want to show Enum "string" rather than numeric value.

I didn't find if I rowDataBound which we use in ASP.NET, using that I can do this, but not sure how to do it now in WPF.

```
<DataGrid Height="125" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="grdData" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" 
                      GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFBEBEBE" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFBEBEBE" RowHeight="25"  BorderThickness="0" 
                      FontWeight="Bold" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" AlternatingRowBackground="DarkGray" 
                      Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" RowBackground="White" ColumnHeaderHeight="25" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Task Name" MinWidth="30" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" MinWidth="30" Width="50" Binding="{Binding Path=TaskCode}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="50" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Completed?" Width="*" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ProgressBar x:Name="TaskProgress" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Value="{Binding Path=CompletePercentage}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                        

                </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

than in my C# code I put

`grdData.DataContext = dt`

Where dt is my Datatable filled using database simple select query.

Thanks.

Comment: are your DataGridcolumns autogenerated?

Comment: nope, I have a template to put progressbar

Comment: post your datagrid xaml code

Comment: try `grdData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;`

Comment: for what ? I am getting my Grid data shown, but I want to get Enum from my .NET code to be seen rather than numeric value. I get progressbar to work. [other data was coming before fine as well].