# WPF Datagrid binding and column display, not able to display the Data in the DataGrid after binding the DataGridTextColumn Header

Tags: datagrid

Initially I was generating a dataGrid with AutoGeneratedColumns = True getting values from a dataTable. However the number of columns for each dataset is fixed and I would like to name them accordingly and therefore named them in the code but if the Tab was not selscted when I runed the code then I was getting an error that the Index is out of range.

I decided to do AutoGeneratedColumns = False and manually define my columns. However in the sequel my data dataGrid was empty and my data not displayed. The Data Table name is Underlyings and it is generated at runtime, before that its not even there.

Below my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=Underlying}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="462,145,0,203" Name="dataGrid3" Width="872" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="In" Binding="{Binding FirstColumnName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="InL" Binding="{Binding SecondColumnName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total  " Binding="{Binding ThirdColumnName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And in the code thwe following

dataGrid3.ItemsSource = Underlying.DefaultView

However I think that XAML binding would not work for me because my datatable is generated at runtime so there is nothing to bind to at design time. 
Any Ideas how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not set the ItemsSource property but rather use the DataContext property of the DataGrid and use templating in the XAML as in the question here: [WPF: Binding to DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335907/wpf-binding-to-datagrid?rq=1)

Comment: I have done exactly that but still my data do not appear in the datagrid. Do i need to adjust something in the Properties

Comment: <DataGrid ItemsSource ="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="462,145,0,203" Name="dataGrid3" Width="872" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="In" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstColumnName}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="InL" Binding="{Binding Path= SecondColumnName}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total  " Binding="{Binding Path = ThirdColumnName}" />



                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>

Comment: I have also placed in the XAML instead of DataGrid ItemsSource DataContext , but still with no success....Thanks for your input so far.

Comment: @Chris Can you show how you construct Underlying? Are you setting it as the DataContext after it is populated or before?

Comment: I define the dataTable like thi: s DataTable Underlying = new DataTable();   Then I populated this table with a selection of  Data from another DataTable defined in the same way..

Comment: I populate the dataTable Underlying with a simple for loop with elemnets that are all double

Comment: @Chris Only thing I can think of is that your DataTable is defined as a member variable and not a property. Is that the case?

Comment: @0_weisman thanks for the reply. Well I assume that dataTable is defined as a member variable since I havent done anything more that defining as previously noted. Would you be kind enough to let me know can I define it as a property? In this way I can check it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure it'll work, there is some debate over whether DataTable can be bound effectively to a DataGrid, but if you want it to be a property define it so:          `public DataTable Underlying { get; set; }`  Your columns should be added with the same name used in your binding of course, so for example:  `Underlying.Columns.Add("FirstColumName", typeof (double));`  Hope that helps.

Comment: @ 0_weisman thanks a lot for your so far feedback and input. I will give it  a shot and let you know!